# Event when SwiftUi Menu is opened

Tags: swiftui

Is there any way to know when Menu control in SwiftUI is about to open OR open? I am sharing Menu code from implementation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu("Options") {
            Button("Order Now", action: placeOrder)
            Button("Adjust Order", action: adjustOrder)
            Button("Cancel", action: cancelOrder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's not possible to do that yet even with the latest swiftui, but you can achieve this with a custom menu. I also use custom menu/picker to achieve this.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/72248463/12299030.

Comment: I submitted feedback FB10667247 requesting sample code for this in the Menu doc page, it must be possible! I would guess we are just putting onAppear in the wrong place.

Comment: i don't think so. at least without new Xcode feature.

Comment: I submitted FB13155990 to request new SwiftUI `Menu` APIs accepting a binding to a Boolean visibility state. Such an API would not only provide a reliable way to know when the menu is visible, but also a way to alter menu visibility programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is my try. Unfortunately the closure will fire once.

```
{
    var onFirstAppear: (() -> ())?

    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Group {
                ForEach(data) { item in
                    Button(item.title) {
                        selection = item
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: onFirstAppear)
        } label: {
            label
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for macOS and just need to know when *any* menu is open, you could use `NSMenu`'s `didBeginTrackingNotification` and `didEndTrackingNotification` notifications (don't know any UIKit-based solutions):

```swift
struct MenuTrackingEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
  static var defaultValue = false
}

struct MenuTrackingViewModifier: ViewModifier {
  @State private var tracking = MenuTrackingEnvironmentKey.defaultValue

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .environment(\.trackingMenu, tracking)
      // These are the important bits: they observe when a menu (a SwiftUI `Menu` view,
      // a `.contextMenu` view modifier, the app's menu bar, etc.) is opened and closed.
      .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSMenu.didBeginTrackingNotification)) { _ in
        tracking = true
      }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSMenu.didEndTrackingNotification)) { _ in
        tracking = false
      }
  }
}

extension View {
  func windowed() -> some View {
    self.modifier(MenuTrackingViewModifier())
  }
}
```

From this, you can then apply the `.windowed()` view modifier to some parent view, and inside a subview, use `@Environment(\.trackingMenu) private var trackingMenu` to know when a menu is open.

If you wanted to know it was *that particular `Menu`* that was opened, you'd likely need to use a project like [SwiftUI Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect) to extract the underlying `NSView` for its `.enclosingMenuItem` and compare it to the notification object's given `NSMenu` (see the section of the README titled "Keep instances outside the customize closure").